# Pycharm update reference automatically

Tags: python, reference, pycharm

I'm a new Pycharm's user, and in my project, I need to turn a python file in a directory. This file contains a lot of functions and so i would like reorder my project creating a new directory that contains new python files with the functions cited previously. So my question is:
Is there a pycharm functionality that update automatically all references (for example import) in project? 
I have searched something like this but i haven't found a good solution. 
Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1):

> go to File >> Settings >> Project >> Project Interpreter

select the setting icon there and click on more

here click in last option (Interpreter Paths).

add your modules directory location here.

> restart Pycharm

Comment: Thanks for replay @Rajiv, but at the end I have solved with the option 'Move' (right-click on function -> Refactor -> Move)